# How does uninstall process work in windows?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

When I'm uninstalling a program from control panel how does it know what components and features are installed on the machine? If I have the `.msi` file I can use ORCA to take a look inside windows installer database and see all the actions and components in the package. But if user have deleted `.msi` file then how does windows installer knows about installed features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the installation, a copy of the MSI ( smaller because it's been stripped of media ) is cached in the C:\Windows\Installer directory using a short hash filename. (example: a60a04.msi )  Also when the standard actions PublishComponents, PublishFeatures and PublishProduct are run during the installation a bunch of meta is written to  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer  ( actually HKLM or HKCU depending on the ALLUSERS property ).   The Windows Installer uses all of this information to have an understanding of the installed products and to know how to perform repair, resilience, maintenance (add/remove features) and uninstalls.  It's also used by the MSI API to provide information when requested.

Comment: FYI: the media isn't stripped in Windows 7 and later in order to avoid an 'unknown publisher' UAC prompt during a maintenance operation.

Comment: Thanks Michael. The trivia gets by me now and then.

Comment: Hey @ChristopherPainter, would you happen to know what is checked against the MSI that is run once a uninstall call is made? Does it need to be signed? Other than the product and upgrade code, what else is checked? What prevents an uninstaller from stopping services and deleting files from other applications?